# Is this the best practice of checking if DyanmoDB table exists?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to search the web for any other way / function, and I came out with this:

```
public static boolean isTableExist(Table table){
    try {
        table.describe();
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there any chance to get rid of the try catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the way if all you want is to check if the table exists. However, if you intend to create the table if not exists, you could use the API: [TableUtils#createTableIfNotExists](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/util/TableUtils.html#createTableIfNotExists-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest-)

Answer (score 2):

This way works and doesn't cause problems or hangs. I don't specifically know of other ways.

Comment: Any idea why is it like that? I think that is a base function which DB should have

Comment: @roeygol Well db might not work this exact way. There may not be a need to check for existance - and so not implmented by default. Or at least no such method I could find.